# Find all the accumulation points of the set $\{2/m-3/n:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and prove that they are accumulation points

Tags: real-analysis

The set of accumulation points is given by $A=\{0\}\cup\{\frac{2}{k}:k\in \mathbb{N}\}\cup\{\frac{-3}{k}:k\in\mathbb{N}\}$
To prove that $A$ contains all accumulation points of the set $\{2/m-3/n:m,n\in\mathbb{N}\}$, we will assume there is a point $x\notin A$, which is an accumulation point. 
Since $x$ is an accumulation point, there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x-\epsilon, x+\epsilon)$ has no point of the the form $0,2/k, or -3/k$.
If we take the sum $2/m-3/n$, with at least one of them less than $\epsilon/2$, and $2/m>3/n$, the sum would be at least $\epsilon/2$ away from $x$. This would mean that the only such numbers in the interval $(x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)$ have $2/m<\epsilon/2$ and $3/m<\epsilon/2$. Thus $n<6/\epsilon$ and $m<4/\epsilon$.
So there would only be a finite number of elements of the form $2/m-3/n$ in the interval $(x-\epsilon/2,x+\epsilon/2)$. Therefore $x$ is not an accumulation point.

This is how I've started but I would appreciate any help, because I'm still confused.

Comment: Welcome to MSE, great job in explaining what you have done so far! When you say "Since $x$ is an accumulation point", perhaps you meant to say "Since $x\notin A$" (note that $A$ is easily seen to be closed). Also, when you say "with at least one of them less than $\epsilon/2$, and $2/m>3/n$" it seems to me that it would be better to remove the "and $2/m>3/n$" part, and only say "with at least one of them less than $\epsilon/2$". The complementary condition to this is that both $2/m$ and $3/n$ are greater or equal to $\epsilon/2$, which could only happen for finitely many pairs $(m,n)$.